# Larvel5: Authenicated user in Service Provider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I created ServiceProvider, and put there some logic for building menu. This logic based on authenticated user. But, `Auth::user()` `Auth::getUser()` wont work, looks like session not booted.

I put my logic in `boot` method.

Temporary solving the problem, I create `middleware` and put logic there, but I dont think it's a correct.

So ServiceProvider it's not correct place for this(similar) logic? Or where better place for working with user?

For example:

```
class MenuServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot() {
      if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()) { // here Auth::user is null
           $this->createAdminMenu();
      } else {
           $this->createDefaultMenu();
      }
    }
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand what you are doing. If you are building a menu for your view - this should be in your View Constructor

Comment: I think this should be in a View Composer - http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers

Comment: yeah, view composers works perfect, but here another logic, I dont share any data.. So that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Well first you should be checking to see if the user is actually logged in:

    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin())

If your user is not logged in, that call would always fail.

Comment: @Oddman Here another problem. In boot method, session provider does not boot yet...

Comment: @DmytroGaliievskyi yeah I've just played with this myself - what you need to do is create a bit of middleware that gets called. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out while also struggling with the problem just recently. The issue, as you pointed out in a comment - is that session information hasn't even started yet when service providers are loaded - that poses a problem. The solution is to create a piece of middleware that you can configure in your Http Kernel class that loads it automatically for every request.

So, given your code above, you might have something like this:

```php
<?php    
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;

class MenuMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()) { // here Auth::user is null
            $this->createAdminMenu();
        } else {
            $this->createDefaultMenu();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, in your RouteServiceProvider - simply register the middleware in the global middleware array.

Comment: I solve this in another way, I'm wrapped in view composer, and compose it only for layout. But your answer is correct :)

Comment: Yup, agreed - tbh I think a composer is a much better approach here considering the logic required is code pertaining to the view.